# Breeze failing silently while parsing metadata

Tags: metadata, breeze

Trying to get going on breeze but encountering the worst kind of error, which is none at all.  It appears the metadata that I am producing is not being accepted by breeze.  I know currently there are some issues with the metadata, such as 'foreignKeyNamesOnServer' has incorrect values in it and a bunch of others.  The metadata I am producing can be viewed here (too large):
http://pastebin.com/ycP4jXxn

```
var serviceName = 'http://www.dockyard.com:8080/rest';
var entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager({serviceName: serviceName});
var entityQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery();
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("application")

entityManager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
   });
```

So the behaviour I am seeing is no javascript errors related to metadata parsing, the metadata is returning ok with 200 OK.  The hit to /rest/application is returning 200 OK with the following data.

```
[{"@id":1,"id":1,"name":"dsad","deploymentStrategies":null,"versions":null,"groups":null},{"@id":2,"id":2,"name":"sss","deploymentStrategies":null,"versions":null,"groups":null},{"@id":3,"id":3,"name":"fdsfs","deploymentStrategies":null,"versions":null,"groups":null},{"@id":4,"id":4,"name":"fdsa","deploymentStrategies":null,"versions":null,"groups":null},{"@id":5,"id":5,"name":"dasda","deploymentStrategies":null,"versions":null,"groups":null}]
```

Promise is calling the error callback with: cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated

The contents of the metadata store:

```
{"namingConvention":{"name":"camelCase"},"localQueryComparisonOptions":{"name":"caseInsensitiveSQL","isCaseSensitive":false,"usesSql92CompliantStringComparison":true},"dataServices":[{"serviceName":"http://www.dockyard.com:8080/rest/","hasServerMetadata":true,"jsonResultsAdapter":"webApi_default","useJsonp":false}],"_resourceEntityTypeMap":{"platform":"Platform:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.dockyard","application":"Application:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","host":"Host:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.host","groupdeploymentstrategy":"GroupDeploymentStrategy:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","dockyard":"Dockyard:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.dockyard","configurationentry":"ConfigurationEntry:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model","hoststrategy":"HostStrategy:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","dockerimage":"DockerImage:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.docker","version":"Version:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","docker":"Docker:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.docker","hostproviderconfig":"HostProviderConfig:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.host","hostprovider":"HostProvider:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.host","metadataimpl":"MetadataImpl:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model","deployment":"Deployment:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.dockyard","hosttype":"HostType:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.host","group":"Group:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","groupimplementation":"GroupImplementation:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","deploymentstrategy":"DeploymentStrategy:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.dockyard","groupdeployment":"GroupDeployment:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application","metadata":"Metadata:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model"},"_structuralTypeMap":{},"_shortNameMap":{},"_ctorRegistry":{},"_incompleteTypeMap":{},"_incompleteComplexTypeMap":{},"_id":0,"_deferredTypes":{}}"
```

I am pretty sure this error is related to Metadata store not being populated correctly from my metadata.  Just wondering why Breeze is not throwing any type of error when it is encountering invalid metadata?

---

Edit:

After debugging the parse metadata call it appears that [Breeze Metadata Schema Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema) is out of date.  At a quick glance this is what it looks like has changed:

- Key name "structuralTypeMap" has changed to "structuralTypes".
- "structuralTypeMap" use to be a object with the key as the EntityTypeName and value was the Entity definition.  Now it appears that "structuralTypes" is an array with the Entity definitions.

Suggestions also there should possibly be an exception thrown if the metadata doesn't contain any structuralTypes?  Currently it is failing silently which isn't very helpful for debugging.

Comment: Not sure what's happening but try calling MetadataStore.fetchMetadata directly and see if you can handle the error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear they you've jumped into the deep end of the pool before learning to swim. I admire your bravery but I'm not surprised that you're struggling to stay afloat. You're not following any of the easy paths we've set out for you. I assume that is because none of these paths are suitable to your situation.

On the bright side, you've reinforced by sense that we soon must make it easier for developers who get their data from a custom REST service.

### Problem #1

The Query results do not identify the `EntityType` and you didn't mention that you wrote a custom `JsonResultsAdapter` to cope with that. Your question and your `MetadataStore` contents below suggest that you are using the out-of-the-box Web API adapter which wouldn't know what to do with the JSON query results.

Here is one item in the JSON payload from your query, reformatted for readability

```
{
  "@id": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "name": "dsad",
  "deploymentStrategies": null,
  "versions": null,
  "groups": null
}
```

There's nothing in there to indicate to which `EntityType` this data belongs. Just looking I have no idea what type this is. Breeze won't know either.

You'll need to learn about the ["JsonResultsAdapter"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-service-data-mapping) which is how Breeze interprets JSON data arriving from the server and maps it into instances of `EntityTypes`.

The [Ruby Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/intro-spa-ruby,) has a custom [JsonResultsAdapter](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/CCJS-Ruby/client/app/services/breeze.jsonResultsAdapter.js,). It depends upon the fact that the server is explicit about the type of each object it returns; see how every Rails view adds a `$type` node (for example, the [sessions:index view](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/CCJS-Ruby/rails/app/views/breeze/sessions/index.rabl,)). This is the approach to take if you can control what the server sends the client.

The [Edmunds Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/edmunds,) has a custom [JsonResultsAdapter](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/Edmunds/Edmunds/app/jsonResultsAdapter.js,) that has to infer the type by examining the characteristics of the JSON data. It's kind of a forensic exercise that you only want to indulge if you have to do so.

## Problem #2

The `MetadataStore` you serialized is empty of all type information. Here it is reformatted for legibility

```
{
  "namingConvention": {
    "name": "camelCase"
  },
  "localQueryComparisonOptions": {
    "name": "caseInsensitiveSQL",
    "isCaseSensitive": false,
    "usesSql92CompliantStringComparison": true
  },
  "dataServices": [
    {
      "serviceName": "http:\/\/www.dockyard.com:8080\/rest\/",
      "hasServerMetadata": true,
      "jsonResultsAdapter": "webApi_default",
      "useJsonp": false
    }
  ],
  "_resourceEntityTypeMap": {
    "platform": "Platform:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.dockyard",
    "application": "Application:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application",
    ... a bunch more ...
  },
  "_structuralTypeMap": {
    
  },
  "_shortNameMap": {
    
  },
  ... more emptiness ...
    
  }
}
```

I'm not really surprised, having discovered problem #3.

### Problem #3

Your raw metadata doesn't match a format that Breeze understands. It looks like you cobbled it together by hand. It sure doesn't look like anything I recognize. It doesn't match the CSDL format from Entity Framework. It doesn't match the "Breeze Metadata Format" that you'd see when you exported a `MetadataStore`.

It's in trouble almost immediately. Here is how you start the definition of your first type:

```
"structuralTypeMap": {
   "Group:#com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application": {
       "shortName": "Group",
       "namespace": "com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application",
```

Here is how it should begin:

```
"structuralTypes": [
{
  "shortName": "Group",
  "namespace": "com.psidox.dockyard.controller.model.application",
```

I accept your point that the [Breeze Metadata Schema Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema) is incorrect. We should fix that.

I'm sympathetic with your argument that Breeze should have thrown an exception. I can see why it didn't throw. It simply ignored all the nodes that it didn't understand. A lot of parsers do that, not that that is a sufficient excuse.

In this case, it ignored the "structuralTypeMap" node and everything it had to say about types. When the parser was done, it had learned nothing at all about the types. Breeze can't know how many types you'll specify but it could act suspicious if there are none.

I confess I personally never thought to use this metadata schema description as my guide. That would be just about the hardest possible way to write metadata.

I suggest that you look at the documentation topic [**"Metadata by hand"**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand).

### In sum

1. Please examine a simple example first. Maybe Edmunds. Maybe Ruby.
2. Learn to write metadata by hand; it's not hard.
3. Learn about the `JsonResultsAdapter`

We do hope soon to offer specific guidance for the developer who has a "vanilla" REST data service.

Comment: I am using Java in my backend and from what I've seen it certainly could see some more love in terms of examples.  I did notice there is an example for creating metadata in github/IdeaBlade/Breeze/tree/master/Samples_Unpublished/Java.  It appears this example is a work in progress so I shouldn't be too hard on it but code quality isn't quite up there.  I used it a little bit as reference but had to rewrite from scratch as it assumes that one has access to hibernate configuration but this isn't the case for JEE scenarios as the configuration is usually abstracted away.

Comment: In regards to your points, 1) I was assuming that breeze assumed data it received from a certain RESTful URI was what designated the entity type and this "resourceEntityTypeMap" data structure was what mapped it.  3) Metadata shouldn't be too terribly off.  Unfortunately I found the metadata by hand stuff a bit hard to follow so I fell back to trying to decipher the metadata schema.

Comment: Ultimately though I must admit I am starting to shy away from breeze.   Getting deeper in starting to see that it doesn't really respect true REST architecture.  True, REST doesn't make it particularly easy to do transactions but I wouldn't trade that for a single end-point model, which is basically just RPC all over again.  I would give breeze another chance if I saw that it was embracing things like [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) instead of this custom schema format and true REST architecture.

Comment: Please don't give up the ship just yet. Our Java guy should be following up soon. As for REST (and let's not get into "true REST" ok because only Fielding seems to know), you are not alone in wanting separate PUT/POST/DELETE/PATCH endpoints. We have adapters for that coming soon. We're not backing off of our internal JavaScript representation of metadata but translating from a json schema source is a reasonable request. Not really a showstopper for you is it? The other stuff, sure.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't mean to sound like a REST nazi.  But yes definitely looking for separate resource endpoints.  A json schema adapter would be awesome.  In regards to your Java guy, if he wants to see the direction I've been going can be viewed [here](https://github.com/smysnk/dockyard-controller/blob/master/src/main/java/com/psidox/dockyard/controller/breeze/NewMetadataBuilder.java).  Thanks for response!

Comment: I like that you've used individual classes to represent the parts of the structure - I was going to refactor to that after I got all the bugs worked out in my list-of-maps approach, but never got to it.  
Regarding the `Configuration` object - I realize it's not generally accessible from the controller, but since the metadata need only be generated once, I thought perhaps it could be done in a place where the `SessionFactory` is first created.
- "the Java guy"

Comment: I can't remember why I needed `PersistentClass` (and thus `Configuration`) to generate the metadata.  Maybe it was something to do with foreign keys or component types.  If you've found a way to do it that only depends upon `SessionFactory`, that would be much better.